# scrollIntoView onClick reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello I have a few buttons and I want to scroll to them when clicked.

```
 const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

 useEffect(() => {
     // I´m not using useRef. is there other way to automatically scroll to the element and stop at 0 0 of the page?
 })


<div style={{height: '10000px'}} />
<button onClick={() setActive(1)}>button 1</button>
<button onClick={() setActive(2)}>button 2</button>
<button onClick={() setActive(3)}>button 3</button>
<div style={{height: '10000px'}} />
```

as you can see there´s a lot of scroll caused by those 2 divs. the idea is to scroll down and when you reach the buttons and click the one you need. the page scrolls to that button leaving it in the top of the page

[image]

```
image 1: scroll in random position
image 2: when you click on button 1
image 3: when you click on button 2
image 4: when you click on button 3
```

Comment: On clicking buttons where do you want to scroll? Which div to want to scroll to when clicking any button?

Comment: to the top of the page. 0 0 (adding it to the question) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scrolling react view to top there is a simple function.

use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

inside your code try this.

`<button onClick={()=> window.scrollTo(0, 0) }>button 1</button>`

edited:

I could come up with this solution after you edited your question.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const button1Ref = useRef();
  const button2Ref = useRef();
  const button3Ref = useRef();

  const handleScroll = ref => {
    window.scrollTo({
      behavior: "smooth",
      top: ref.current.offsetTop
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: "10000px" }} />
      <div>
        <button ref={button1Ref} onClick={() => handleScroll(button1Ref)}>
          button 1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button ref={button2Ref} onClick={() => handleScroll(button2Ref)}>
          button 2
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button ref={button3Ref} onClick={() => handleScroll(button3Ref)}>
          button 3
        </button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "10000px" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please try it out. Let me know if this is what you asked for.

**Edited after question asked in comment for using single component with Ref and using that component in multiple numbers:**

If you want to use a single component for button then try this,

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: "10000px" }} />
      <MyButton>button 1</MyButton>
      <MyButton>button 2</MyButton>
      <MyButton>button 3</MyButton>
      <div style={{ height: "10000px" }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const MyButton = props => {
  const buttonRef = useRef();

  const handleScroll = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      behavior: "smooth",
      top: buttonRef.current.offsetTop
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={buttonRef} onClick={handleScroll}>
        {props.children}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: but doing this will leave the button off screen

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you. On button click you want to scroll it to window top right?

Comment: no worries. I just added an image to explain it. check it out!

Comment: is there a way to move it to the button component? I can convert it to <MyBytton />

Comment: Hey. Try the last piece of code. It will solve your issue to use buttonComponent. @handsome

Comment: I mean can we define the ref inside the component? so we dont have to define it in the main component. and that will allow us to create multiple buttons and dont have to worry about defining the ref in the main component

Comment: Yes you can.. Again check the last piece of code. This should answer your question.

Comment: Tip: incase you want to put ref to a child component, use "forwardRef" HOC to wrap your child component and propagate the ref as deep as you like until u find a html element to set it.

Answer (score -1):

Here you want to use an [event handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

```js
  const handleClick = (e) => {
   //  scrollIntoView logic and set state
  }

  <div onClick={handleClick}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
//action
const goDown= (e) => {
    const anchor = document.querySelector('#some-id')
    anchor.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' })
}

// click to scroll
<Link onClick={goDown}>Choose Health</Link>


//element you want to scroll to
<div id='some-id'>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution, and use a code block instead of a snippet for non-runnable code.